# TOC - put Part headings in small capitals whilst conserving other characteristics

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I am creating a TOC and would like to put the Part headings in small capitals whilst conserving their current size, etc (MWE below).

I tried `\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\scshape}`but this results in losing the boldface and reducing the size.

Is there a way to conserve these characteristics with small caps?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chap 1}

\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Chap 1}
\chapter{Chap 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have a font with bold small caps?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `\usepackage{libertine}` - added to MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\bfseries\scshape}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chap 1}

\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Chap 1}
\chapter{Chap 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]